# app.get doesn't work properly express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, redirect, express

```
app.get('/:id', function (req, res){

   UserModel.find({ user: req.params.id}, function (err, user){

         if (err) throw err;

         console.log(user + '\n\n');

         res.render('profile.ejs', {

                username: user[0].user,
                avatar: user[0].avatar,
                followers: user[0].followers.length,
                following: user[0].following.length

         })

   });

});
```

I don't know why, when, for example, I write `<a href="/<%= username %>">...</a>`, I go to `/randomuser/` instead `/randomuser`. Is this a problem if I try to render a png in `/:id`, from a static directory? Because I think yes! The png doesn't render, but in other page that doesn't end in `/` it works.

Answer (score 0):

Not positive I understand the question but you should be able to get it to work by changing

> app.get('/:id', function (req, res){

to

> app.get('/:id/', function (req, res){

the png should render
if it dosent work let me know

Comment: I tried both, but anyone worked. With `app.get('/:id', function (req, res){`, when I try to access to `localhost:8888/randomuser`, suddenly, I'm redirected to `localhost:8888/randomuser/`, I don't know why! I think that's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You Will Get Redirected to /randomuser/ or /randomuser depending on what the route is in app.get.
It doesn't matter as far as I know.
let me know if you have any other questions

Comment: That's what is supposed to do, but, if I use `app.get('/:id', function (req, res){` or `app.get('/:id/', function (req, res){`, the result is the same, `localhost:8888/randomuser/`, when I want `localhost:8888/randomuser`, but `app.get('/:id', function (req, res){` doesn't works for this.

Comment: I have a new doubt, why when I in `localhost:8888/user/randomuser`, or even in `localhost:8888/randomuser/`(because I don't know why I can't go to `localhost:8888/randomuser`), I can't render an image from a static directory. For example, if I write in `localhost:8888/user/randomuser` this `<img src="<%= avatar %>">`, the image doesn't appear. And `<%= avatar %>` is `./randomuser/avatar.png`.